# Capybara Rspec how to refresh page and see changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, pry

I have one project where I can use binding.pry to pause execution during Capybara rspec testing, and continually refresh the page in the browser while making changes to the code for that page.

This is EXTREMELY helpful for me.

I have a new project that won't pick up new changes to my code when I refresh the page.

I can't tell what in the projects is different, but how can I configure my app so a refresh during debug in Capybara will pick up changes?

Different server, different config? HELP!

Comment: that's pretty cool, never thought to do that.  Sounds like spring isn't running?  That's where live reload comes from in dev, not sure if that runs in test.

Comment: Turns out I needed to do   config.cache_classes = false in config/environments/test.rb

Comment: speeds up my development time by factors of 100s because I basically develop/view inside a test